# terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'

Tags: c++

**terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'**

**what(): basic_string::replace**

Hi, guys. I was wondering if you could help me figure out the error in bold. I'm making a program that interprets addition and multiplication expressions (with parentheses allowed). It uses recursion but no special data structures. Anyways, I don't believe I need to post the entire program. It's compiling and I was testing it with the expression "5*3" which should return the string "15". For some reason, I'm getting an out-of-bounds error when I use the replace() function for a string. I was wondering if you have any idea why based on the following snippet of code. Any help greatly appreciated.

```
size_t firstast = eq.find_first_of('*'); // position of first asterisk 
    if (firstast != std::string::npos) {
        // Set num1 and num2 equal to the respective numbers to the left and right of the asterisk:
        std::string num1, num2; 
        size_t num1begin(firstast), num2end(firstast);
        while (isdigit(eq[--num1begin])) 
            num1.insert(0, 1, eq[num1begin]);
        while (isdigit(eq[++num2end]))
            num2.push_back(eq[num2end]);
        // Replace the space of the multiplication equation num1*num2 with its evaluation:
        eq.replace(num1begin, num2end - num1begin + 1, multStrs(num1, num2));
        evaluate_equation(eq);
    }
```

Comment: I just read that quickly, but you should probably run this program through `valgrind` to point out the many out-of-range errors. For instance, in the first `while` if the string starts with a digit (which I assume it often does), you will test `eq[-1]` at some point, and you probably don't want to do that.

Comment: All we can really say is, "debug your code."  Otherwise you're really asking us to do that for you, aren't you?

Comment: @ereOn, I think you found my problem

Comment: @remyabel: That shouldn't matter, according to the specifications of the replace() function on cplusplus.com

Comment: @user2967799: I guess I did yes. There might be some other errors after that but one thing is sure: if you don't fix that, anything that happens after it is undefined. Please, next time try to show some more effort into finding your problem: `valgrind` would have told you about such a mistake in a second.

Answer (score 0):

One error lies here:

```
while (isdigit(eq[--num1begin])) 
  num1.insert(0, 1, eq[num1begin]);
```

If the string starts with a digit immediately followed by a `*`, this will test `eq[-1]` and that's not defined.

You may replace the `[]` operator call with `.at()` to explicit the error in a reliable manner (but that wouldn't fix anything - it is just for the exercise).

Also the next `while` probably has the same/mirrored problem with the end of the array (even though I would expect most implementations of `std::string` to be secretely zero terminated - but don't assume this, **never**).

Comment: The `while`-expression doesn't fail if the input string starts with a digit followed by `*`. It does fail, if the input string starts with a `*` character. And it fails if the input string starts with one or more digits.

Comment: @IInspectable Not sure what the difference is here: my explanation states an obvious not-working case but I never stated it was the only one. Also starting with a digit itself is not enough: there has to be no non-digit characters between the first digits and the following `*` or the loop will exit before evaluating the faulty conditional.